# Incorrect ion-icon background on navbar

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I created a navbar like this:

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
  <ion-title>{{team.name}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="goHome()">
        <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

The problem is that the Home button is showing with some strange grey background like in the image below:

[image]

I'm using Ionic2 RC3

How can I fix it?

Comment: i think that was button background color....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
  <ion-title>{{team.name}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only item-right (click)="goHome()">
        <ion-icon name="home" ></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```